# Problems with message boxes in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

- Windows 7 Home Premium X64
- Visual Basic 2010 Express SP1
- All Visual Studio updates installed except for a Visual C++ security update

The problem:

1. Sometimes message boxes in a console app close after clicking the ok button on one before all the messages are displayed. It is just supposed to display one message box after another.
2. Same code as above, A message box in a console app will sometimes minimize to the taskbar before displaying all the messages after the OK button is clicked on
3. The same code as the above 2 problem but in a Windows form app will display all of the message boxes, But.sometimes won't show the form at the end like it should.

The bugs I know happen when I run the programs from VB itself, don't know about the EXE outside of VB.

I know it isn't my code because others have tried it and had no problems.

What can I try to fix it?

EDIT: Code for the one with the button and form:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim anInteger As Integer = 42
    Dim aSingle As Single = 39.345677653
    Dim aString As String = "I like pancakes"
    Dim aBoolean As Boolean = True

    MsgBox(anInteger)
    MsgBox(aSingle)
    MsgBox(aString)
    MsgBox(aBoolean)

End Sub
```

End Class

Code for the console ones:

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim anInteger As Integer = 42
    Dim aSingle As Single = 39.345677653
    Dim aString As String = "I like candy"
    Dim aBoolean As Boolean = True

    MsgBox(anInteger)
    MsgBox(aSingle)
    MsgBox(aString)
    MsgBox(aBoolean)



End Sub
```

End Module

Comment: You meant *I know **it is** my code because others have tried it and had no problems.*? BTW, codez?

Comment: paste some code here for additional info...

Comment: You have to post enough code to reproduce the problem. That's the only way that we can tell what you're doing wrong.

Comment: I would try, in this order: 1) stop assuming it's not your code (it *is* your code). 2) post some code so people can help you. 3) work out what's different between your machine and the "others" that don't have problems.

Comment: Well it would certainly appear from your code the the message boxes should display in order and wait for the OK to be clicked before showing the next one and so on. There is no issue with the code as posted. I would question why you want to display message boxes in a console app though as the whole point of this is that the output is all to the console. If you want interaction with the user (via a message box) then you should be using a winforms app.

Comment: I was just following the beginner tutorials on Microsoft's website. I used a console app first as I didn't see a point in displaying the message boxes and then having a form there doing nothing. Thanks

Comment: Anyone think I should try reinstalling?. It seems to only be a problem with Visual Basic, Visual C++ doesn't do it. Thanks

Comment: I reinstalled it and found out it's not actually closing the message box. But is instead moving it behind the CMD prompt. Sometimes when it does it you can still see part of the CMD prompt peaking ok. When it does it the CMD | thing starts flashing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you've run the exact code you posted above, and you're getting the symptoms you describe... I would say that it is probably a hardware problem, specifically a problem with either your mouse or your keyboard.

*You* believe you are clicking the mouse button once (to close the OK button). But just at the moment that the system is trying to show you the next message box, *it* thinks you hit the mouse button a second time - or maybe it thinks you hit the SPACE bar - either way, it closes the next message box instantly.

Prove (or disprove) my theory:

1. First, wait until after hours, or until you're the only one in the building. (Hint: One of your "friends" might be playing a joke on you, using some sort of remote-access technology.)
2. Remove your mouse and keyboard. Borrow the mouse and keyboard from some other computer (at least temporarily) and plug them in instead.
3. Reboot. (Shouldn't need this, but try it anyway -- just to be sure.)
4. Start your program. When the first message box appears, wait to make sure it doesn't go away on it's own. Then carefully click the mouse ONCE on the OK button. Repeat for the other 3 message boxes.
5. If the problem still happens, try it again, except don't use the mouse at all - use your keyboard's SPACE bar to dismiss the message boxes.
6. If needed, try it one more time, this time with the ENTER key.

If the problem still hasn't gone away, try booting in SAFE MODE -- perhaps some other software is interfering! Also try doing a virus scan, even if you're fairly certain you don't have a virus.